# Of the different virtualization project available- QEMU, KVM, Xen, VirtualBox which one should a beginner pick

Tags: open-source, virtualization

I am interested in virtualization related projects. However there seems to be plenty of options in this field. Which project should i start working on given the above choices. I want to work on on of these projects going forward. I am familiar with the basics of virtualization methods available and basic interfaces. Have been using VirtualBox for more than 3 years now.

Comment: For what kind of projects? What are your goals?

Comment: Just contributing and improving them. I want to work in the virtualization field as a form of work going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ask yourself what type of code you want to contribute. If it is more on the *binary-translation* side, your best choice is QEmu since it does all the core work for KVM. KVM on the other hand, is an architecture that sits upon QEmu and leverages the Linux kernel's scheduler. So if IPC, process management, signals etc are your thing, jump into KVM. i would suggest that you study the architectures of these hypervisors and then decide what you want to get into.

This was a specific example. Virtualization is much more than hypervisors. Look into [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/). It is to virtualization what Android is to smartphones.

Another interesting thing to look into, to begin coding would be [libvirt](http://libvirt.org/). It is the underlying library that powers most of hypervisor-agnostic virtualization frameworks and orchestration tools.

Comment: Thanks i will keep this in mind while deciding :)